# how to move the element position by js without flicker

Tags: javascript, html, web

For some reason, I have to move a div position from middle to top on the page, I have to use pure js:

```
    addLoadEvent(function(){
       ...
    initDivPosition
       ...
    });

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if(typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I test it in browser, I found: the div first in the middle position and very quickly jumps to the top.
How to make it at the top when page loading finish, so user can't notice it jumps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the approaches: instead of calling the positioning function on `load` event, call the function immediately after the div definition, e.g.

```
<div id="divToBePositioned">...</div>
<script>
    initDivPosition();
</script>
```

The function will be called **immediately** after the div is rendered.